# Rotation speed measurment

Tags: optics, measurements, laser, interference, interferometry

Could anyone please explain with simply how we can measure the rotation speed of an object using the Sagnac Interferometer ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagnac_interferometer explains it pretty dang clearly.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get the measurement principle from wiki page.

Comment: I wonder if your confusion lies in the fact that the rotation you are measuring is the rotation of the Sagnac interferometer as a whole.  If you want to measure the rotation of another object you need to attach a Sagnac interferometer rigidly to it so that the whole Sagnac rotates with the object.

Comment: It would help if you could edit the question to expand on why you weren't able to figure this out from the Wikipedia page.

Comment: Sure I will specify my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you imagine the Sagnac interferometer to be a circular ring cavity (as it is in some variants of optical fiber ring gyros) lying on a table, then the light which is moving clockwise and the light which is going counter-clockwise, will take the same amount of time to  go once around the ring.

If the ring starts rotating, then the light traveling in one direction will now take less time  than the other to make one loop around the ring. This phase shift is detectable as an interference between the two outgoing beams.

In modern laser gyros, the laser field is made within the resonant gyro cavity and the phase shift is turned into a frequency shift.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Which one will take more time and which one will take less time. As per my understanding if the setup is rotating in the clockwise direction the beam which is moving in the clockwise direction will arrive late isnt it ?